# Reversed file is empty after piping

Tags: command-line, sort

I have just started learning Linux and having problem with understanding piping.
I am wondering why reversed.txt is empty?
I want to save unsorted file first, then pass to reverse sort, then save to reversed.txt.
My line of code:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | tee > unsorted.txt | xargs sort -r | xargs cat > reversed.txt
```

Comment: This sounds more like a homework question than one related specifically to Ubuntu. Perhaps StackOverflow would be the place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command has a number of issues.

1. Pipes connect standard output to standard input. Since you redirect the standard output of `tee` to a file, there's nothing to go to the input of the remainder of the pipeline. It should be

   ```
    cat file1.txt file2.txt | tee unsorted.txt | ...
   ```
2. `xargs` turns standard input into *arguments* of the given command. The `sort` and `cat` commands expect their arguments to be filenames. So you're asking it to run `sort` (and then `cat`) on files named as each of the lines in the original files, rather than on the lines themselves.

   ```
    cat file1.txt file2.txt | tee unsorted.txt | sort -r | cat > reversed.txt
   ```

However the final `cat` is superfluous, so all you need is

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | tee unsorted.txt | sort -r > reversed.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood that the main problem was redirect to file after tee so that there was nothing to flow further horizontally.

Comment: you could skip the last redirect too by doing `sort -ro reversed.txt` but I don't think there is any advantage really.